# Apache - The name

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, httpd

I am working on a migration to a newer virtualized server. The old one has Apache 2.2.4  according to the old servers `phpinfo()`. The new one with the most up to date has 2.2.3. How can this be assuming no trickery is involved? The old one is years old.

A lot of the guides I reference use apache2 in folders names and many of the conventions. The newest version of things, as I understand it is called httpd. Did apache change the name from what it originally was? (i.e. break the web server component into its own project called httpd, I realize the original daemon was probably still called httpd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long ago there was NCSA HTTPd. Problems were found, and fixes were applied. What was created was a patchy HTTPd, so the project took on the name "Apache httpd". Other projects came under the "Apache" umbrella, so the web server is now "httpd", versus "Apache Tomcat" or "Apache Ant". Debian-based distros still use the "apache" name for the web server though.

Also, [this](http://www.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting/?sc_cid=3093).

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance that the old server, the one with 2.2.3 is running Red Hat or another commercial Linux that back-ports security patches into one fixed version for its entire lifetime.  The newer machine with 2.2.4 could actually have more vulnerabilities, especially if it was laid down directly from the Apache project and never maintained.

Run one or both of these commands on both machines to see what distribution they are:

```
cat /etc/*release*
lsb_release -a
```

Comment: The old version has 2.2.4, not the new one. It is CentOS so your back-port idea could be plausible.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the distribution you are using and the repository.

if the newer virtual server is using a more 'stable' release of the same distribution, chances are they haven't updated the Apache2 version in the repository, because it doesn't need to be updated, or the package maintainer has applied specific security patches and fixes to an older version.

either way, you'll probably want to make sure your package management is up to date, and then update your system's packages.

Comment: Fair enough, but the odd thing is the newest version at apaches httpd project page (http://httpd.apache.org/) is 2.3.5. I don't understand how there can be a 2.2.4 out, when the highest on the homepage is 2.3.5.

Comment: Cancel that, I was misreading the version numbers.